# CSS file not having any effect

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have included a CSS file in my project for my own CSS use, but it is not working or having any effect on my page

the file default.css

```
.feedbackText{
display: none;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 50px;
color: blue;
}
```

in the HTML file:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<?=THEME_CSS?>bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<?=THEME_CSS?>default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Later in the HTML file

```
<span id="invalidPasswordFeedback" class="feedbackText"></span>
```

The path is right, i checked it from the source in the browser, the PHP code is just a path to CSS files.
Thank you

Comment: Have you checked in the developer tools, whether another rule is more specific and thus overriding some of your properties?

Comment: Like Siroki said, use developer tools to confirm that the css is actually being loaded. you may have a css path issue.

Comment: What is th output you expect and what is the one you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

As some commenters allready said, your rule is probably overridden by another, more specific rule.

You can fix that by making your CSS-Selector more specific, e.g.:

```
span#invalidPasswordFeedback.feedBackText{
   /*Your rules*/
}
```